# Deployed Applet Suddenly Not Working

Tags: actionscript-3, file-upload, flex4, flash-builder

I put together an applet that uploads images via `as3httpclientlib` to a servlet. The applet works fine in debug mode (through flash builder) and **until** today it worked when deployed.

From the servlet logs, it appears the servlet never receives the image(s) byte stream, therefore my hunch is the applet is not *posting* the multipart data.

Can anyone suggest what I should do next to find the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you ran into problem described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html#contentType):

> In Flash Player 10 and later, if you
>   use a multipart Content-Type (for
>   example "multipart/form-data") that
>   contains an upload (indicated by a
>   "filename" parameter in a
>   "content-disposition" header within
>   the POST body), the POST operation is
>   subject to the security rules applied
>   to uploads:
>
> 1. The POST operation must be performed
>      in response to a user-initiated
>      action, such as a mouse click or key
>      press.
> 2. If the POST operation is
>      cross-domain (the POST target is not
>      on the same server as the SWF file
>      that is sending the POST request), the
>      target server must provide a URL
>      policy file that permits cross-domain
>      access.

So I think you should run your application using debugger and check Flex client logs for exceptions described above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the upload process in my applet is started by a "mouse click" and the target url, via an apache proxy, is the same as the url that served the applet. Further, when I use flash builder debugger the applet works fine. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you to use some kind of debugging proxy like Charles http://www.charlesproxy.com/ and check the real queries and answers from server. And compare them in debug and production mode where you have problems.